# Вывод url миниатюры последнего поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос, делаю вывод последней записи, и хочу получить url изображения поста. Url получаю но в пути к картинке нету разделителя '/'. Вот такой урл на выводе получаю.

```
 url(" http:="" new.wglife.com.ua="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2017="" 12="" dsc05105-1.jpg").
```

Скажите пожалуйста, что не так делаю. Функции зачистки строки от слешей у меня нету, странно почему его убирает на выводе.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $recent["ID"]), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
        echo '<div class="full-width-container" style="background-image: url("'.$image[0].'")"><div class="recent-attachments"><div class="recent-date">'.get_the_date('d.m.Y').'</div> <div class="recent-author">'.get_the_author_meta('display_name', $recent["post_author"]).'</div> <h1 class="recent-title"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .$recent["post_title"].'</h1></a><button class="recent-button"><a href="'.get_permalink($recent["ID"]) .'">'.Читати.'</a></button></div></div>';
    }
```

Comment: только при выводе последнего поста такое?

Comment: Да. У меня на странице ещё выводится список постов с изображениями, но там все нормально. А здесь почему-то такая проблема

Comment: сделайте var_dump($image[0]);

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для получения миниатюры поста использовать функцию [get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_post_thumbnail_url)

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

    echo '<div class="full-width-container" 
               style="background-image: url("' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($recent["ID"]) . '")"> ...
}
```

Comment: Тот же результат, без слэшей путь

Answer (score 0):

Всё, тема закрыта. Вопрос решил костыльным путём правда, почему то в выводе строки через echo с кокотенацией убивались слеши в ссылке к изображению. Пришлось дедать вывод строки делать без конкотенации а на каждую инициализацию функции отдельно echo прописывать. После этого путь вывело корректно.

Answer (score 0):

У вас повторяющиеся двойные скобки

```
style="background-image: url("")"
```

Так должно работать:

```
style="background-image: url('')"
```